# App name appears in a separate dialog window

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am calling a dialog box through an activity , when alarm goes of.
The dialog box appears when alarm goes of. 
When back button is pressed there is another Dialog box , which diaplays the app name.

[the dialog that appears when alarm goes of](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wb8wm.jpg)

[The Dialog that appears with app name when back button is pressed, after the first dialog appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0zJW.jpg)

This is the intent for alarm :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, HydrateNotifier.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
```

This is the Dialog definition inside `OnCreate()` within `HydrateNotifier.class`:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Hydrate Time");
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Enter the amount of water");
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Update", this);
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

**Need Solution for :**

1. The dialog box that appears when alarm goes of , disappears when touched outside its boundary. Please provide a logic to make the dialog box remain.

2.On pressing the back button , when the dialog box appears , the dialog box closes and another dialog box is visible with the app name ,as shown in image.
How do i make it not appear?

I have set `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog"` in the Manifest for the class in which the dialog is defined.

Answer (score 0):

1. Setting the setCancelable method to false on Alert Dialog will make the dialog persist even if user taps on outside the dialog.

   ```
   AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
     alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Hydrate Time");
     alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Enter the amount of water");
     alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
     alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Update", this);
     AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
     alertDialog.show();
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks. Why does the name appears in a separate dialog box ?

Comment: Not sure about that. Do you have any other dialog calling from your OnBackKeyPressed or any other method?

Comment: Can you also show the code of where are you calling this alertdialog from?

Comment: That dialog is inside OnCreate() within an activity. That activity is called when an alarm goes of

Comment: Can you show the code of that HydrateNotifier class?

Comment: `code`(
public class HydrateNotifier extends Activity{

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 
 AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
 alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("HydrateTime");
 alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Enter the amount of water");
 alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Update", null);
 
 AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
 alertDialog.show();

 
 }

 
 

} )

@Mahfuz Islam Bhuiyan  sorry for the late reply

Comment: I don't see any possibility of creating another dialog in this class.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this [App name showing after dialog close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45017988/app-name-displayed-when-finish-dialog-activity). It will solve the issue mentioned in this question.