# App name displayed when finish() Dialog Activity

Tags: android, dialog

I want to secure my app with a fingerprint authentication dialog activity, it works, but if I choose to close the dialog here is what happens :

[image][image]

If I `finish()` the activity it flashes on the screen but it's still annoying.
I am using `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog"` theme.

Is there any way to prevent this from poping up ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually I just figured out why. It's because I was using `AppCompactActivity`. Using a simple `Activity` fixed the problem.

Comment: Life saver! Accept this as this is an open issue in other cases. Took me two days to come across this, can't believe it was such a simple mistake

Comment: @Omar Aflak, Thank you.